# Running shell script to do git push w/ ssh key, Permission denied

Tags: git, teamcity, ssh-keys

I'm trying to set up TeamCity to run a shell script that pushes everythin to my test server.

The build process looks like this:

- Fetch all code from GitHub.
- Run UnitTests and build
- Shell script to push to test server (amazon ec2) using git

The problem here is that the shell script isn't allowed to push to the test server, when it's run by TC.

I get "Permission denied (publickey)."

I had the same problem when running the script from a shell but got it working by adding the key to my user (same user that runs TC) with ssh-add.

So I can run the script manually, but would like to get TC to run it.

Anyone know if there's a differance running shell script from TC or in a shell on the server?

..fredrik

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions for this problem:

- create an ssh key for the TC user with which you need to enable the submitting to the git remote repository (this is the better solution)
- copy your key to the TC user's `~/.ssh/` directory (which I do not suggest)

*Update:* You can check it by sudoing to the TC user and trying to ssh to the destination (with verbose parameter). If the ssh works then git can connect to the destination.

Comment: I've tried the second solution, didn't work. And the first solution I don't think is viable since Amazon requires a .pem key file for all ssh. And the strange part is that running the script with the TC's user works just fine from a shell but not from TC itself